# Cant find suitable Android NDK for Unity 2019.3 and Unity 2020.1.0a14

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I want to build **64 bit App Bundle** using Unity, so I need Android NDK. However, I can't found suitable NDK for both Unity **2019.3.X** and **Unity 2020.1** (alpha).

last time, I choose Android NDK 19c but failed:

[image]

so far, I still not found NDK r19 (**19.0.5232133**)

any idea?

Comment: same problem here, unity forces this exact ndk version, which you can't download from google.

Comment: Download NDK 19.0.5232133 here https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19-windows-x86_64.zip

Answer (score 4):

If you downloaded the NDK provided with the HUB, you can try unchecking the "**Android NDK installed with Unity (recommended)**", in the **Edit** -> **Preferences**, and set the path manually. This worked for me.

[Option in external tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUBax.png)

Path to NDK should be in ../2019.3.0f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/android-ndk-r19

Otherwise, You can try to download an older NDK, like the NDK provided in this post https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-android-ndk-missing.689122/

Comment: replacing the path manually worked for me. In unity the default path does not include "/android-ndk-r19" you have to set it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your NDK Path. If it looks something like this, then it's wrong:

```
\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK\android-ndk-r19\
```

Just copy everything from the android-ndk-r19 and put it directly under the existing NDK folder. Just tick "Android NDK Installed with Unity" and you're all set.

Regards Bj

Comment: I can confirm this works - I moved my NDK contents from AndroidPlayer\NDK\android-ndk-r19\ to 
AndroidPlayer\NDK\ and was able to build.

Comment: Btw in the last version 2019.3.0f3 the problem and the fix is the same.

Answer (score 1):

So I downloaded NDK + SDK via unity hub and then deleted the sdk again (since I already have my own version of the android sdk installed).

This is how I got the required NDK.